# JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.0.0 log with min version

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using jQuery migrate minify version but i still get this output "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.0.0" in console

How can I disable this?

Comment: Just remove the code from line 23 to 25 and then minify the resulting file....https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/src/migrate.js#L23

Comment: fix the problems that you needed it for and then uninstall it. that's what it's there for.

Comment: I can't fix the problem I'm using a plugin that is not updated, the other option is goin back to jQuery 2 I'm not sure witch is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using migrate.js from your own server and can change the file, then Just remove this line from migrate.js and it will work fine for you.

```
window.console.log( "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed" +
    ( jQuery.migrateMute ? "" : " with logging active" ) +
    ", version " + jQuery.migrateVersion );
```

Comment: I'm using the minify version

Comment: Take the un-minified version, remove the lines that I have mentioned. After you have removed the desired lines, go to https://jscompress.com/ and compress your migrate.js file and save it to your local file.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
window.console.log( "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed" +
    ( jQuery.migrateMute ? "" : " with logging active" ) +
    ", version " + jQuery.migrateVersion )
```

for

```
null
```

in jquery-migrate.js

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was caused by a plugin, Yoast SEO.

How I found it:

- disabled all plugins
- enabled one by one
- updated that one which caused the issue